# LWUIT Label: Using image as a label

Tags: java, image, java-me, label, lwuit

I am using LWUIT but a problem I have is that when I use an image as a label like this:

```
mapScreen = new Form("Map");
        try 
        {
            Image image = Image.createImage("/res/Map_new_1.jpg");
            mapScreen.addComponent(new Label(image));
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.print("Error\n\n"+e.getMessage());
            mapScreen.addComponent(new Label(e.getMessage()));
        }
```

I am able to display the image even though it is larger than the screen of the mobile phone. I am also able to scroll vertically but I am not able to scroll horizontally. How can I fix this problem so that I will also be able to scroll horizontally?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use  `Form.setScrollableX(true);`

Comment: Hi jmunoz,
I have tried it but still, I wasn't able to scroll horizontally.
Do you know some other way to work around this? Thanks

Comment: are you sure that your image is bigger than the screen?

Comment: Yup. I am sure of that since I cannot see the other parts in the right side of the image but I can scroll up and down. Just the scroll horizontally doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can try `mapscreen.setScrollableX(true);`

It will work. I have tried it. It's working correctly for me.